# How prevent rebuilding via make in Linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, cross-compiling

I have built package in cross enviroment (via using *make* command) on server. Package build was successful. I want run *make check* natively on target architecture, use command to copy build directory on target machine

```
rsync -a -H -A -X libssh2-1.4.0 user@machine:/path/to/package/libssh2-1.4.0
```

Also, I sync time on server and target machine.

On the target machine I execute `make check`. But all sources are rebuilt, as if the building had not been performed before.
How can I prevent this rebuilding?

Comment: `rsync -a` enables `-t` which preserves modification times so I wouldn't expect time to be the issue. Why is it rebuilding? Run `make -d check` to print detailed debugging info. What does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Some dependency files were newer than the target. For example, stdio.h (dep file) was newer than channel.lo (target). Stdio.h is placed in fakeroot and copyed by me without preserving time attrs. After copy with preserving attrs libssh2 stopped rebuilding.